# ASP.NET WebApi with Protocol Buffers - Error handling

Tags: asp.net-web-api, error-handling, json.net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

**Context:**

What i have now:

1. 3-tiers app
2. Client-Server communication

   - Server: ASP.NET WebApi v1
   - Client: HttpClient
3. Serialization - JSON.NET

However,

1. JSON.NET is slow
2. JSON.NET is even slower on the first call (i take it this is because of serializer assembly generation on the fly). This is too slow for me - according the requirements i need to optimize the first call as much as possible.

I am considering using [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) instead of JSON.NET. On a simple PoC app it has shown more than twice as fast result, even the first call, especially when i'd pre-generated the assembly for protocol buffers serializer.

So i've implemented MediaTypeFormatter using protobuf-net and everything works well except one thing - serializing errors.

This is how the exceptions are passed to the client:

```
public class ExceptionShielderAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, context.Exception);
    }
}
```

Internally, CreateErrorResponse method creates an instance of HttpError (which inherits from Dictionary[string, object]) and writes it to the content.

By default, protobuf-net knows nothing about HttpError so I've tried to add HttpError to protobuf runtime model as follows

```
typeModel.Add(typeof (HttpError), true);
```

but it did not help, when i call

```
typeModel.Compile("ModelSerializer", "ModelSerializer.dll")
```

it throws **InvalidOperationException: No serializer defined for type: System.Object.** 
Likely due to  type of Dictionary[string, object] which is not supported by protobuf-net.

**Questions:**

1. Is there anything I can do to serialize errors properly  or should i avoid using out-of-the-box errorhanding and implement my own error handling on the server that uses well-know types that protobuf is aware of?
2. Is protobuf a good choice for my problem at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed work around the problem by adding a special case to my protobuf media type formatter:

```
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        try
        {
            if (type == typeof(HttpError))
            {
                value = CreateDto((HttpError) value);
            }
            model.Value.Serialize(stream, value);
            completionSource.SetResult((object)null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            completionSource.SetException(ex);
        }
        return (Task)completionSource.Task;
    }

    private HttpErrorDto CreateDto(HttpError error)
    {
        if (error == null) return null;

        return new HttpErrorDto
        {
            Message = error.GetValueOrDefault<string>("Message"),
            ExceptionMessage = error.GetValueOrDefault<string>("ExceptionMessage"),
            StackTrace = error.GetValueOrDefault<string>("StackTrace"),
            ExceptionType = error.GetValueOrDefault<string>("ExceptionType"),
            InnerException = CreateDto(error.GetValueOrDefault<HttpError>("InnerException"))
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a snippet that enable serialization of System.Web.Http.HttpError using protobuf-net

```
namespace WS
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using WebApiContrib.Formatting;

    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.Add(new ProtoBufFormatter());

            ProtoBufFormatter.Model.Add(typeof(HttpErrorProto), true);
            var model = ProtoBufFormatter.Model.Add(typeof(HttpError), false);
            model.IgnoreListHandling = true;
            model.SetSurrogate(typeof(HttpErrorProto));
        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class HttpErrorProto
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public String ExceptionMessage { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public String ExceptionType { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public String InnerException { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public String MessageDetail { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public String Message { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 6)]
        public String ModelState { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 7)]
        public String StackTrace { get; set; }


        public static implicit operator HttpErrorProto(HttpError error)
        {
            return error == null ? null : new HttpErrorProto
            {
                ExceptionMessage = error.ContainsKey("ExceptionMessage") ? error["ExceptionMessage"] as string : null,
                ExceptionType = error.ContainsKey("ExceptionType") ? error["ExceptionType"] as string : null,
                InnerException = error.ContainsKey("InnerException") ? error["InnerException"] as string : null,
                MessageDetail = error.ContainsKey("MessageDetail") ? error["MessageDetail"] as string : null,
                Message = error.Message,
                ModelState = error.ContainsKey("ModelState") ? error["ModelState"] as string : null,
                StackTrace = error.ContainsKey("StackTrace") ? error["StackTrace"] as string : null
            };
        }

        public static implicit operator HttpError(HttpErrorProto error)
        {
            return error == null ? null : new HttpError
            {
                Message = error.Message
                ...
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very useful solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to use a surrogate; something like:

```
typeModel.Add(typeof(HttpError), false)
    .SetSurrogate(typeof(MyError));
```

Where `MyError` is a custom type of yours which:

- has a conversion operator (implicit or explicit) to/from `HttpError`
- is suitable for use from protobuf-net

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This did not help though. I did as you said but typeModel.Compile() thrown ArgumentException: Repeated data (a list, collection, etc) has inbuilt behaviour and cannot use a surrogate.

Comment: It is a Dictionary[string, object]

Comment: @olldman it *is* a dictionary? Or it *has* a dictionary? But fundamentally: object isn't going to work. If you could, for example, tostring the values during the translation from model to DTO, for example

Comment: it IS a dictionary - please find its source here http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/HttpError.cs , As for your suggestion, I don't think it is possible as WebApi does it intenally, when CreateErrorResponse is called (here - http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs).  Looks like custom error handling is the only way to go :(

Comment: @olldman that's awkward. I could probably code around it, but it won't work today